# html page failed to show css background-image

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I`m working on a VS2010 ASP.NET Web Application project, and I`ve added a html page to it. The problem is when starting debug(F5) , this page fail to show some icons which were set in css file , but when opening html page directly, those background-image is showing perfectly.

css codes are:

```
.leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
background-image: url('images/spritesheet.png');
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent,transparent),url('images/spritesheet.svg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 270px 30px;}
```

and related javascripts are:

```
var drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
    map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
        edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems,
            poly: {
                allowIntersection: false
            }
        },
        draw: {
            polygon: {
                allowIntersection: false,
                showArea: true
            }
        }
    }));
```

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpDsf.png)

[open directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqx06.png)

I think maybe there are some web-configs limiting the access to resources.
Dose Anybody know how to deal with it?

Thx!

Comment: do you have the site online to check it out ?. You, open the browser tools and see why is not load the image.

Comment: @Aristos I`ve always checked and there is no error reported in both situations . I`m using chrome .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed css codes and it worked:

```
.leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url('images/spritesheet.svg');
background-image: url('images/spritesheet.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 270px 30px;}
```

As you see , in the former codes background-image use svg over png , now I`ve changed to use png over svg.

So the only different lies between svg and png , and I`m gonna learn details about svg. I still guess it has something to do with the way browser interpret svg which is given in a debug mode website.